# Add authentication to an existed API using WSO2 AM

Tags: authentication, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created an API using WSO2 EI that looks like `https://localhost:8243/services/ABC`.

Then I want to create another API that gets above API as the endpoint in order to add authentication. So how can I pass value to URL pattern and endpoint to get that?

When URL pattern is **/xyz**, and the endpoint is `https://localhost:8243/services/ABC`. It points to `https://localhost:8243/services/ABC/`**xyz** that not my endpoint.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a custom sequence to the API.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="header_sequence">

   <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
       
</sequence>
```

This drops the resources and not appending to the path.

Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/mapping-the-parameters-of-your-backend-urls-with-the-api-publisher-urls/#mapping-the-parameters-of-your-backend-urls-with-the-api-publisher-urls

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are trying to invoke the backend `https://localhost:8243/services/ABC` via the API created in APIM. You can try out the following to achieve it,

In the API created in APIM, you can simply add the URL `https://localhost:8243/services` as the endpoint and then create a resource path as `/ABC`.